# no comparison in if() judgement but seems give a boolean value

Tags: c++

```
if(!word.size()){
        return true;
    }
```

[whole code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlAsn.png)

*how here use string.size() lonely to return a boolean value?*

I googled the string.size() method although i already know it returns a int value,but here it works like a true/false method;

Comment: Do you aware of the result of `!N` for any number N, particularly `!0` and `!1`?

Comment: IMHO the same and better is `if (word.empty())`. One more example of challenge sites not teaching the best practice.

Comment: @drescherjm That would change the effect of the program in the case that `word.size()` is nonzero. There's no `else{ return false; }` in the original code.

Comment: Tactical note: [For many reasons  you should never post images of text information like code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Pedantic note: *i already know it returns a int value* Careful there because it's going to be unsigned and very likely larger than `int`

Comment: The fact that code places the functions in a class called solution shows how terrible those random internet solutions can be. Using a class only as a namespace without any data members is one of the most disgusting things for me in C++.

Answer (score 3):

The language checks if the condition inside the conditional is `true` or `false`. In this case, the `int` value gets converted into a boolean. If the size returns `0` this will get converted to `false`, any other value will be converted to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of things in C++ can be coerced to Booleans. Off the top of my head.

- Booleans are trivially convertible to Booleans
- Numbers (`int` or `double`) can be converted to Boolean; zero is false and anything else is true
- Streams (like `fstream` instances or `cout`, for instance) can be converted to Boolean and are true if the stream is in "good" condition or false if there's a problem

As indicated in the comments, you shouldn't use this in real code. `if (!word.size())` is silly and confusing an should only be seen in code golf challenges. Coding isn't just about making the computer understand what you mean; it's about making sure future readers (including yourself six months down the line) understand as well. And `if (word.empty())` conveys the exact same intent to the computer but is much more understandable to the human reader at a glance.

So why does C++ allow this if it's discouraged? Historical reasons, mostly. In the days of C, there was no dedicated `bool` type. Comparisons returned an integer, and the convention was that `0` meant "false" and anything else (usually `1`) meant true. It was the programmer's job to remember which things were Booleans and which were actual integers. C++ came along and (rightly) separated the two, making a special type called `bool`. But for compatibility with C, they left in the old trick of using integers as Booleans. Successor languages like Java would go on to remove that capability. `if (myInteger)` is illegal in Java and will give a compiler error.

Comment: Sidenote about `double`: If you haven't already, you'll find it can be annoyingly difficult to get exactly zero.